# Loop to Monitor Line Count Growth Using wc -l

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-substitution, printf

I've written a short bash script to monitor the line count growth (wc -l) in a file which is receiving results from a loop.

Thus:

```bash
printf "Name of file to monitor\n"
read file

printf "How long to monitor file growth in minutes\n"
read time

printf "Interval between loops\n"
read s

a=$((time * 60))                                   # works out overall time in seconds
b=$((a / s))                                       # no of loops

for i in $( eval echo {0..$b} )
do
    printf "Loop number: %-10.2d Interval: %-10.2d Line Count: %-10.2d.\n" $i  $s  $'wc -l $file'   
    sleep $s 
done
printf "finished\n"
```

I'm having problems with the last argument of the `printf` line. I'm not sure how to correctly  state the `wc` function within the `printf` function.

Comment: To get `wc` to output the number use `$(wc -l $file)`. And for good programming practices, you should use quotes (either single or double) around variables. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) post.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `wc -l filename`, it outputs filename next to the number of lines in it. And when a command substitution is not wrapped in double-quotes, it undergoes word-splitting, i.e expands to multiple words if it has any spaces in it. And, lastly, `printf` uses the format over and over until it consumes all given arguments [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57747767/printf-in-bash-function-add-new-line-to-the-wc-l-results).

The correct way is:

```
printf "Loop number: %-10.2d Interval: %-10.2d Line Count: %-10.2d \n" $i  $s  $l "$(wc -l <"$file")"
```